# Using S3 to upload in PHP using PHP DI

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using dependency injector to setup S3's credentials:

```
// AWS S3 for PDF
$container['s3_pdf'] = function ($c) {
    // Only load credentials from environment variables.
    $provider = CredentialProvider::env();

    $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'version'     => 'latest',
        'region'      => 'ap-southeast-2',
        'credentials' => $provider
    ]);

    return $s3;
};
```

Then whenever I want to upload something I'd do:

```
$result = $this->s3_pdf->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'       => 'reports.omitted.com',
    'Key'          => 'temptest1.pdf',
    'SourceFile'   => 'assets/temp.pdf',
    'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
    'ACL'          => 'public-read',
    'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
    'Metadata'     => array(
        'param1' => 'value 1',
        'param2' => 'value 2'
    )
));
```

I want to be able to upload to S3 from different functions in the code without having to write the bucket name everytime, am I able to have the `s3_pdf` container return a function that only takes `sourcefile` and runs some code to figure out the sourcefile & destination & uploads to S3?

I know that I can use a class that would contain this function I'm after and use an object of that class in the functions where I need S3 but I'd rather use the dependency container if there is a way to do so.

Comment: make a new `$this->putObject()` function that wraps `$this->s3_pdf->putObject()` and injects your configuration

Comment: @Scuzzy thanks for the comment. How can I pass parameters to that function?

Comment: I'd suggest that you could merge two arrays together, your wrapper function provides the base and you feed in overwrite parameters. see array_merge() and even array_merge_recursive()

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest example of my suggested wrapper function possible:

```
class WhateverYourClassIs
{
  function putObject( $key, $sourceFile )
  {
    return $this->s3_pdf->putObject(array(
      'Bucket'       => 'reports.omitted.com',
      'Key'          => $ke,
      'SourceFile'   => $sourceFile,
      'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
      'ACL'          => 'public-read',
      'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
      'Metadata'     => array(
          'param1' => 'value 1',
          'param2' => 'value 2'
      )
    ));
  }
}
```

Or with an array

```
class WhateverYourClassIs
{
  function putObject( $overloadedConfig )
  {
    $baseConfig = array(
      'Bucket'       => 'reports.omitted.com',
      'Key'          => NULL,
      'SourceFile'   => NULL,
      'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
      'ACL'          => 'public-read',
      'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
      'Metadata'     => array()
    );
    return $this->s3_pdf->putObject( array_merge_recursive( $baseConfig, $overloadedConfig ) );
  }
}

$this->putObject(array(
  'Key' => 'temptest1.pdf',
  'SourceFile' => assets/temp.pdf'
));
```